# FFMPEG > End the video with a still image

Tags: image, ffmpeg

This is the command I use :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i test.mp3 -ignore_loop 0 -i waves_hori.png -filter_complex "overlay=2:H-200" -c:a copy -c:v h264 -shortest -y test.mp4
```

Is it possible to add an end image for 5s?

Comment: Before or after the audio ends?

Comment: Ideally before ... But if it's after, that's fine for me too ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do this automatically by using a pipe instead of having to get the audio duration and subtract time.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i audio.mp3 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "overlay=2:H-200=format=auto,format=yuv420p" -c:v rawvideo -c:a pcm_s16le -shortest -f matroska - | ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -an -i - -loop 1 -t 5 -i end.jpg -i test.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -shortest output.mp4
```

Why 2 commands and a pipe?

1. The first ffmpeg command is similar to your original command, but the output given to another ffmpeg. This allows you to take advantage of `-shortest` to automatically make the video match the audio duration.
2. The second ffmpeg command takes the video from the previous command, skips the beginning 5 seconds of the video, then uses the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter to concatenate the 5 second image to the video.
3. Using a pipe avoids temporary files and generation loss.

`end.jpg` must to be the same width, height, and aspect ratio as `background.png` to concatenate properly. If it is not then add the scale, scale2ref, crop, or pad [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank you so much ! FFMEPG is a hell of a machine ... it's still confusing, but it works perfectly! Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to include this end image for 15s, if it's a snippet?

For example, take from 00:00:05 to 00:00:25 a 30s mp3, with the end image triggered at 00:00:10s?

Comment: @Dreuh Asjust the existing `-t` and `-ss` from 5 to 15, and add `-t` and `-ss` input options before the mp3. See `-ss` and `-t` [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options).

Comment: Yes ! Thanks :) !